# VBA .Formula Vlookup with Wildcard Returning Type Mismatch (Simple)

Tags: vba, excel

I am referencing another closed workbook to perform a VLOOKUP. Manually typing into the cells works, however this code in VBA is returning an error "Type Mismatch." What am I missing?

```
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(i, 5).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""*""&$D" & i & "" * "" & ",'\\MyDirectory\[MyWorkbook.xlsx]MySheet'!$B:$D,3,FALSE)"
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula that you want I guess is

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&$D1&"*",'\\MyDirectory\[MyWorkbook.xlsx]MySheet'!$B:$D,3,FALSE)
```

Is this what you are tying?

```
Cells(i, 5).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""*""&$D" & _
                      i _
                      & "&""*"",'\\MyDirectory\[MyWorkbook.xlsx]MySheet'!$B:$D,3,FALSE)"
```

The trick is to copy the formula from the excel cell and then replace every `"` with `""`

**Test Scenario**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    Cells(i, 5).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""*""&$D" & _
                          i _
                          & "&""*"",'\\MyDirectory\[MyWorkbook.xlsx]MySheet'!$B:$D,3,FALSE)"
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: I have updated the post. you may have to refresh it to see the changes

Comment: I don'e see any space. See the screenshot that I have attached